# Horizontal scrollbar on browsers suggests white space to the right of my site, what's causing it?

Tags: css, browser, scrollbar

I've been developing this site for a while and suddenly today I noticed that the horizontal scrollbar on my browser was showing and was allowing the site to be scrolled an inch or two to the right.

The whole site is only 960px wide and my screen resolution is 1680px so clearly it should fit with plenty of space.

The site still displays exactly the same but the scrollbar is annoying me.  I've tried adding borders to everything using the `*` selector in CSS but nothing seems to be protruding that extra inch.  I've also used the Google Chrome console to highlight different sections of the site but none of them are causing the problem.

Every browser shows the same problem, do you have any explanations?

This is the site in question: http://compressmycode.com/

Comment: You probably should have posted some of the relevant code in your original question.  Now that you seem to have fixed the problem, people reading this in the future will have nothing to gain.

Comment: The problem has not been solved.  Read the comments on the first answer below.  The problem is in the facebook code so I can't really post any code as it isn't mine that is causing the problem.

Comment: Regardless, my point still stands, **whenever** this question is solved, it will be useless to future visitors without **your** included code.  When I looked at first, I thought it _might_ be the FB iframe causing this.  Can't you make it a fixed width and position it accordingly?  Otherwise, you can put it in a fixed width container div and set overflow to hidden.

Comment: No, read the comments below, this doesn't work.  This has become a question of how the Facebook code works and how to properly set its width, it's not a bug in my code so showing my code wouldn't help.

Comment: @Nick Brunt:  Do you honestly believe you can alter Facebook's embedded code?

Comment: Did I say that?  I'm asking how to set its width because clearly putting `width="150"` doesn't actually work entirely correctly - at least not when floated to the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the `position:relative` in your `#body-wrapper` style around line 31 of your CSS and use `margin-top:50px` instead of `top:50px`

if you must keep the `position:relative` you can also just apply an `overflow:hidden` to your wrapper to remove whatever overflow may be there, but there are some [inherent dangers](http://www.impressivewebs.com/overflow-hidden-problem/) in doing so.

**EDIT**

Upon further inspection, I've discovered that your `.right` div is the issue. For some reason, its being floated to the right is causing your problems.

Comment: That's fixed it in WebKit but not in Firefox or IE

Comment: i never got it in webkit, and this fixed it for me in firefox

Comment: You're right about the `.right` div.  It's the Facebook code that's causing the issue.  It must be doing some strange things underneath.  Adding `overflow: hidden;` to it doesn't help.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Nick Brunt: Put it in a container div and set `overflow:hidden;` to the container.

Comment: @sparky that's a good solution. i haven't tested but it sounds like it would work

Comment: @Nick Brunt:  Your page is suddenly working now? ... I see no horizontal scroll-bar.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes form your JS. if you disable it, it works perfectly.

More precisely with the facebook button: 
div#body-wrapper > div#site-title > div.right > div.fb-root > div

setting this to overflow: hidden, fixes the problem

Comment: Really? I wouldn't recommend that at all, it will prevent vertical scrolling too! At least use `overflow-x:hidden`, but even that's a last resort.

Comment: your right this is a bad solution. But this is the only thing i could think of atm. Im investigating where it is coming from, updating my answer soon

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. There was nothing that seemed to exceed the width but still there was a scroll bar at the bottom.

My structure of page was:

```
<body>
  <div id='appContainer'>
    <div class='page'>
       <div>All the content along with "Youtube video"
           which meant there was
           an iframe within my page,
           some other stuff like *sharethis buttons,
           Which meant i had to add a few scripts.</div>
       <div>more stuff</div>
       <div>more fancy stuff</div>
       <div>some more stuff with shadows and floating elements</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

***sharethis**: http://www.sharethis.com/#sthash.r7Bx1kDr.dpbs

I'm not sharing the CSS as there was nothing other than box-shadows at the outer levels and top-margin.

Although i'll share how the problem got fixed.
I gave the

```
<div class='page'></div>
```

css:

```
.page{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This fixed the scroll issue for me.
Although the fix was just to find the right parent and give it the above `CSS`

I still would like to know the root cause for the scroll. Kindly share that knowledge if you have it.